# JS / jQuery How to get height of dynamic (responsive) div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have not been able to find an answer that works for me on SO.

Basically I have a div with an image that has fixed positioning. It is responsive and will shrink or grow to whatever the screen size is.

What I want to do is get the height anytime the screen size changes and input it as a positioning value for another div so that it there is no overlapping (due to the fixed positioning).

I can get the height initially but it never changes after the first value when the screen is being resized.

quick demo up here: [link](http://devpeek.com)

look in console to see height being returned. notice that it doesn't change when browser is resized.

**JS**

```
$(function(){

    var explore = $('#explore').height();
    console.log(explore);

    $( window ).on("resize", function() {
    console.log(explore);
    });

});
```

I've also tried `.css("height")` but that didn't fix the issue.

*note the div does not have fixed positioning on this example since it would make the layout more confusing

Comment: `explore` will only have the value at the time you define it, you need to check it's size inside the resize handler

Comment: Bingo! I knew it was something simple. If you post as an answer I'll accept! Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not modifying explore:

Change it as follows:

```
$(function(){

    var explore = $('#explore').css("height");
    console.log(explore);

    $( window ).on("resize", function() {
       explore = $('#explore').css("height");
       console.log(explore);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a resize listener to the window like so:

```
function repositionDivOnResize() {
 // this is where you'll dynamically reposition your element
}

$(window).on("resize", repositionDivOnResize)
```